# I cant use a function returning another function in a express js helper

Tags: node.js, function, express

I have this helper :

```
function loginRequired(msg){   // this is the helper
    return function(req, res, next){
        if (req.user.is_authenticated){ // example
             return next()
         }
         //else
         req.flash('error_msg',msg)
         return res.redirect('/')
    } 
    
   }
```

and I have this route ( I`m using the helper in this route ) :

```
router.post('/new', loginRequired(msg='You are not allowed here'), async (req, res)=>{

// code

})
```

The problem is that the **function returned by the helper** is **not** being **executed**, when I request this route, it keeps loading forever and the content is never sent.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the function returning a function and how you're using it, so the problem is likely elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything obviously wrong with the `loginRequired()` function and how you're using it so the problem is probably elsewhere.  The only thing I see is that if `req.user` doesn't exist, then it would throw.

For further debugging, I would suggest you do this to make sure your route is being matched.

```
function logRoute(msg) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(msg);
        next();
    }
}

router.post('/new', logRoute("/new handler"), loginRequired(msg='You are not allowed here'), async (req, res)=>{

// code

});
```

And, make sure you see `/new handler` in the console.  If you don't even see that, then the problem is further upstream with how your route is declared as it isn't matching an incoming request.  You would have to show us the rest of that code for us to see how the router is being used.